Which materials did Donfeld use to create Wonder Woman's golden lasso in "The Queen and the Thief"?
Does anyone know how to exactly recreate the golden lasso that Donfeld created and that Wonder Woman used in the episode, "The Queen and the Thief," in which she lassos the thief as she stands across the room from him? Does anyone have access to which materials Donfeld used to create her golden lasso?

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  I'm not sure that discussion of practical effects, even if it's on a science fiction show, is really on-topic here.

If re-worded to "What was used to make the Golden Lasso?" it is likely to be on-topic on Movies and TV.SE

@DavidW - Of course it is.

https://www.reddit.com/r/WonderWoman/comments/13mve8h/comment/kejzvrp/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button

@Paulie_D - Per the [FAQ] this perfectly fits the description of "Behind-the-scenes and fandom information" and is absolutely on-topic here, as long as OP restricts themselves to objective questions about the materials.

This version of the 1975 lasso seen in the episode The Bermuda Triangle Crisis (noting that they made multiple versions to go with different costumes) apparently has metal caps at each end. You can see them fairly well in close up.

...signature golden lasso with metal tips...
Lynda Carter "Wonder Woman" Aquanaut ensemble and golden lasso of truth from Wonder Woman


The 2017 movie prop consisted of gold-painted rope with resin caps.

This lot consists of one approximately 20 foot length of gold-color painted rope with cast resin end caps.
Propstore- WONDER WOMAN (2017)
#474. Wonder Woman's (Gal Gadot) Lasso of Truth


